# TargetInvocationException thrown when trying to mock Entity Framework context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

While writing a unit test using Moq & NUnit for a repository (following [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx)), I encounter a TargetInvocationException and I have no clue why it's being thrown.

```
var fooList = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo() { Id = 1, Name = "Something" },
    new Foo() { Id = 2, Name = "Some other thing" }
}.AsQueryable();

var mockedFooSet = new Mock<DbSet<Foo>>(fooList);
mockedFooSet.As<IQueryable<Foo>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(fooList.Provider);
mockedFooSet.As<IQueryable<Foo>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(fooList.Expression);
mockedFooSet.As<IQueryable<Foo>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(fooList.ElementType);
mockedFooSet.As<IQueryable<Foo>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(fooList.GetEnumerator()); 

var mockedContext = new Mock<FooContext>();
mockedContext.Setup(context => context.Foos).Returns(mockedFooSet.Object);
```

The TargetInvocationException is being thrown on that last line. Am I missing something ovbious here? How would I go about fixing this? I'd be thankful if anyone can give me some explanation of what I'm doing wrong here.

**Edit:** Error message

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
----> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Castle.Proxies.DbSet`1Proxy' threw an exception.
----> System.ArgumentException : Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out there were some wrong DLL references. Deleting Moq completely and re-installing via Nuget fixed the problem.

Comment: Could not believe that. I lost one hour trying other solutions first, but this was the right one :)

Answer (score 0):

Foos is a property; use `mockedContext.SetupGet(c=>c.Foos).Return…`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However, changing `Setup` to `SetupGet` does not fix the issue. I added the exception messages to the question.

Answer (score 0):

For me after updating Moq version 4.0.10827 to 4.10.1 the problem has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this after trying the same tutorial, in which I also encountered the same `TypeInitializationException` and `ArgumentException`.

After seeing some of the other answers, I found that I had v4.0.10827 installed.

I updated to the latest (which at the time of writing is v4.16.0.0). After updating I no longer see the exceptions.